# How can store the jest test results in the database

Tags: node.js, jestjs

I am using jest framework to test my Node.js application, it's working fine, Now I have to display the details of the jest runs. For this, I think I need to store the jest results to the database, Is there any way?

Comment: You can store them with custom reporter, but what's the goal? Considering you want to have a history of test results, this is what CI is for.

Comment: @Estus Flask, this is to see the history of test runs.

Comment: I'd suggest to check how it's done with CI then, it seems you outgrew local development. It makes sense to connect test results to specific git commits, and that's what CI does. As I said, this can be done with custom reporter but since this is a very exotic requirement I wouldn't expect a lot of solutions to exist, probably something like https://github.com/zaqqaz/jest-allure